# How to modify an existing Epicor SSRS report by adding fields in dataset and inserting the field as expression in textbox

Tags: reporting-services, epicorerp

I want to modify existing Packing slip SSRS Report by adding a new field to display TNR Number. When I included the field in dataset and tried to add expression and save it, it shows an error:

> Fields cannot be used in query parameter expression

Comment: you'll need to add more info. Edit your question to show your expression and dataset query for a start.

Comment: This error you are reporting sounds like something unrelated to what you are wanting to achieve. It sounds like you have messed around with the Parameters section inside the SSRS dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify default parameters of customized Epicor base reports. Perform the following steps in order to add your field to the Pack Slip report.

1. Navigate to Report Data Definition (RDD) from the Epicor menu.
2. Duplicate the base RDD for PackSlip if it is not yet customized in your system and select the new RDD.
3. Select DataSources-> Report Table-> List and select the Data Source that has the same table name as the table that holds your TNR Number custom field. If this custom field exists in another table, you will need to create a new datasource to that table and link it with a report relationship (more details available in Epicor proprietary documentation accessible via [EpicWeb](https://epicweb.epicor.com/Support/MyEPICweb/Pages/default.aspx)).
4. Click the exclusions tab and either find your field name or add a new exclusion with your field name and uncheck the checkbox that specifies "ExcludeColumn". Click Save.
5. Open the PackSlip RDL file in your SSRS portal with VS / Report Builder. I similarly recommend saving a duplicate copy in your custom directory so that your changes are not overwritten in a future update of the product.
6. Open the SSRS Dataset with the same name as the RDD DataSource you updated in step 4 and modify the underlying query expression to contain your new field. Note that new relationships defined in the RDD do not automatically update this selection query, but they will instantiate a new instance of the datasource on each report run (so you'll need to append the GUID parameter to any new tables in this expression). Add the field to your dataset field list, then add your field to your report in the desired location and save the report.
7. Open the report style form in Epicor ERP and create a new report style for your custom version of the packslip (if this is the first time it is being customized). You'll need to specify your custom RDD as well as the location of the custom RDL(s).